# How to include a patch to a JS library?

Tags: 8, composer

I'm using the Superfish library in my Drupal 8.7.x project. I included it in composer.json like this:

```
 "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "name": "mehrpadin/superfish",
            "version": "2.1",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "source": {
                 "url": "https://github.com/amclin/Superfish-for-Drupal.git",
                 "comment": "use amclin because of pull request 29",
                 "type": "git",
                 "reference": "c11a5ac10f8c99f809858c0384a4c415411778ce"
            },
            "require": {
                 "composer/installers": "~1.0"
             }
         }
    ]
.....
```

Now I found a patch to a problem I have, so I'd like to apply the patch to the JS file automatically. Much like the way I can apply patches to Drupal modules.
Specifically this one:

https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/smallscreen_patch.diff

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Look into composer-patches. Does your composer file include it?

Comment: Yes, I'm already using it to patch Drupal modules. I didn't know I could use it to patch the JS libraries as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevin already mentioned: it can be done using 'composer-patches' in a similar way to patching a Drupal module.

The mentioned patch contained more than I wanted to patch, so I downloaded the patch and added it to a local 'patches' directory. Also, the patch uses a path that starts at 'libraries', while the patch configuration starts one level deeper.

So the patch configuration becomes:

```
....
patches {
    "mehrpadin/superfish": {
        "Fixed nested UL accordion functionality": "./patches/smallscreen_patch.diff"
    }
}
...
```

And the patch itself is changed from:

```
diff --git a/libraries/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js b/libraries/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js
index 9765fed..f5722a9 100644
--- a/libraries/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js
+++ b/libraries/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js
```

to

```
diff --git a/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js b/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js
index 9765fed..f5722a9 100644
--- a/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js
+++ b/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js
```